# Running two servers on same port

Tags: ubuntu, router, apache-http-server

I want to lay up my web server from my Ubuntu Desktop. I have apache2 installed on this desktop and my site is ready to be laid up. I've also got a domain name for my server.

However, my home router is using the external IP of my home network for router settings on port 80. The domain name points to my home network. I don't want to damage or take down the router settings running on port 80. I want my server running without having this weird `https://example.com:8000` (:portNumber) on it.

I think getting a seperate external IP for my computer would make it work. Is it possible ?

I already asked this question on Server Fault, but I got comments that this was off topic and I have to post it on Super User. That's why I'm here.

Any help appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: "my home router is using the external IP of my home network for router settings" -- Did you determine this when connecting from _inside_ (home LAN) or from outside?

Comment: Most ISPs offer the ability to have a 2nd WAN IP assigned to the account, however you'd need a gateway from the ISP with two WAN ports, one of which would either go to a separate router or the same router if your existing one supports dual-WAN interfaces with two WAN ethernet ports. You really don't want to redirect WAN port `80`||`443` on the primary internet router, else you'll run into traffic issues when accessing the internet from that router.

Comment: Does the router offer an option to move the settings website to a different port? What happens if you just try to "port-forward" port 80 to something else?

Comment: @user1686 I haven't tried that. I don't want to do so, because I think I might lose the settings page forever.

Comment: @SarveshM.D A router's WebUI should _**never**_ be accessible from WAN, as it's a massive security risk; instead, if needing access from WAN, it should be accessed via a VPN or SSH server running on the router. Usually, this would have to manually be enabled [binding the WebUI's webserver to all interfaces or both WAN & LAN], as I'm not aware of any router OEM that opens the WebUI by default to WAN due to the inherent security issue it creates. _(There are router OSes that may do so, such as Sophos UTM, but there's significant security within such a router OS underpinning such a setting.)_

Comment: @JW0914 Sorry!. I think when I tried from outside the local network, it showed me the cached page and it was not originally from the router. When I tried from a different device, the router settings page wasn't loading. I've deleted the mistaken comment.

Comment: @JW0914 When I tried to port forward port 80 in my router settings, I got this error `Error: The port of the remote web management is conflicting with of the virtual server.`

Comment: @SarveshM.D To resolve that error, disable remote web management _(e.g. accessing the WebUI from WAN)_, as the WebUI's webserver is still bound to WAN port `80` _(try rebooting the router, else refer to the OEM's support page/router's manual)_. It could also be the WebUI's webserver is bound to LAN `0.0.0.0:80` & `0.0.0.0:443` and if there's an option for it, manually set the WebUI's IP to that of the router's LAN IP _(e.g. `192.168.1.1` or similar)_. The WebUI should never be accessed on port `80` [plain HTTP] as it sends passwords in plaintext since it's not encrypted [HTTPS `443`].

Comment: @JW0914 I found an option to change the WebUI from port 80 to 443, I changed that to 443, now I'm unable to access the WebUI. I tried accessing it through port 80 and also through port 443. I am not able to connect to it now. Please help me get there and I'll reset the settings.

Comment: Even if I cannot run my server, I need the router settings page back. Please don't leave me alone at this point. Please help me solve my problem. @JW0914

Comment: @SarveshM.D What router are you using? You'll likely need to refer to your router's manual/OEM support site, as HTTPS requires an SSL cert for the WebUI's web server, which should either be: baked into the firmware when it's compiled, autogenerated by the router's firmware on first boot, or generated based upon changes made within the WebUI _(it's usually one of the three, not all of them)_. If you're unable to determine how to fix it from the manual/OEM support site, and the router doesn't support SSH or a USB-TTL serial connection, it'll likely need to be factory reset.

Comment: @JW0914 I got the settings page of the router after hours and I was able to log in to that and I immediately changed the setting back to normal port 80 since I felt it was `Okay` to have that weird :portNumber after my domain name than to lose the settings page of the router. I am using a TP-Link Router

Comment: @SarveshM.D Again, **the WebUI should never be accessible from port `80` because HTTP is not encrypted**, so when you log in to the WebUI with the `root` passphrase via HTTP [port `80`], the passphrase is sent in plain text and it gets worse from there: change your WiFi passphrase, it's sent via plain text; set static IPs for devices, the device MACs are sent via plain text; upload an SSL cert, its private key is sent via plain text, etc. **A router is the equivalent of your house key for your digital life** and you wouldn't leave your house key outside your front door for all to access.